# No sound suddenly 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound, soundcard

The soundcard is not detected.

```
$ lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 16
        Memory at 94328000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Memory at 94310000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl

$ sudo modprobe snd-hda-intel
$ aplay -l
aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...
$cat /proc/asound/cards
--- no soundcards ---
```

My kernel:

```
$ uname -r
4.4.0-57-generic
```

Reinstalled `alsa-utils` and `alsa-base`. Still I get:

```
$ alsamixer
cannot open mixer: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Is your firmware configured for HDA or I2S audio? Usually that's found in the BIOS/UEFI menus.